# Should a question marked as a duplicate of a deleted question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23284254/3204827) question is marked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270115/exe-file-generated-by-using-java-8-is-not-working-properly) question.

The second question has since been removed by its owner. Since the question has been removed, shouldn't the question that was marked as a duplicate be automatically reopened since it is a duplicate of a question that no longer exists?

Comment: For those confused: the question was reopened several minutes before this question was asked.

Comment: Did both questions belong to the same author? (I'm thinking about how the question was both eligable as a duplicate target and as valid for self delete)

Comment: @RichardTingle yes, good point which I missed!

Answer (score 4):

It is already discussed on MSE: ["Duplicate of...[deleted post]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post)

The [top scoring answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43727/152859), which is also by a Community Manager (SE employee) says:

> If the question is a duplicate of a deleted question, then it should be deleted as well!

To which I totally agree.

In the specific case of question deleted by its owner it might be different though, and judged case by case in my opinion. Some common scenarios:

1. If the original question was deleted without a good reason (even by its OP) it's better to flag it and ask to undelete it. Stack Overflow is not a personal help forum, so if a question is helpful to others it should stay.
2. If the deletion was justified and yet you don't think the newer question should be deleted as well, vote to reopen it or flag if you don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: in my practice, another pretty common scenario seems to be "flag to re-close" - that is, to close with a different reason or with different dupe target

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the OP posting the same question multiple times and then deleting them? No.

In the case of a [question *posted by someone else* that *already has an answer*?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post) Yes.

This question is a duplicate of a question the OP asked, twice over, in fact.  *The OP's actions aside*, unless we can find a duplicate of another question that was *asked and answered by someone*, we don't have a duplicate situation.

Here's why:

The text of the duplicate is clear:

> This question has been asked before *and already has an answer*. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question. (emphasis mine).

So in this case, no the question should not be closed or deleted *as a duplicate* unless we can actually find one.

The purpose of marking questions as duplicates is to link to existing content. It's not to punish someone for re-asking the same question over and over.

If you see someone posting the same question over and over, please flag for moderator attention, as we have other ways to resolve this issue, and we'll handle closing/undeleting/editing/moving content as necessary.