# Questions marked as duplicate of deleted question

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

So, while checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378835/get-options-value-from-wp-options-table) in the review queue I checked the question it was marked as duplicate of and [it did not exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379399/unserialise-array). It arrived in the re-open queue because of an edit though, not because of the fact that it points to a deleted and thus invisible question. The reply OP gave seems to suggest he owned both questions.

I think deletion of a question should automatically re-open any questions that were closed as a duplicate of that question. It makes no sense to me to keep a question closed if you can't find the answer anymore by following the duplicate-question link.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252507/should-a-question-marked-as-a-duplicate-of-a-deleted-question-be-re-opened?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the deleted post is by the same author.

Comment: @ChrisF I didn't notice that question when I posted this one, but that seems to be more or less an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> I think deletion of a question should automatically re-open any questions that were closed as a duplicate of that question.

In many cases we just want to delete the duplicate too. If both questions are of really poor quality or off-topic, reopening isn't called for. This isn't one of those cases though, so I reopened the question you found in the review queue.

(Even in the case where the OP keeps reposting the same question, *one* copy should remain open, provided it's of high enough quality. Some people will eventually get banned for repeatedly asking/closing/deleting/reposting questions, but I don't see that pattern in this case.)

Comment: Hmm hmm hmm. There are two cases I can think of where that is not necessarily the case: Someone decides to delete their own question for some reason or someone decides to delete their account for some reason. That doesn't imply low quality, just a rage-quit of some magnitude.

Comment: @Sumurai8 So? We still can't *automatically* do anything.

Comment: Hmmm; well, you can automatically add it to the re-open queue for human intervention. The only reason this question seemed to enter it was because they made an edit. How many more of these orphan questions exist?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Adding them to a queue is a much better idea. There are over [118k duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes), so I'm sure there are a lot more orphans to be found.

Comment: @Sumurai8 [Duplicate questions of deleted questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173146/duplicate-questions-of-deleted-questions) shows about 2000 results. Some of those are false positives though, since they were closed a long time ago, before the duplicate link was automatically inserted. There are still a lot of orphaned duplicates in there though.